# xcode tap button while moving with UIViewAnimation

Tags: ios, animation, button, action

I can't make a button action when the button is moving.
Can anyone help me how to hide the moving button when tapping on it?
It is not reacting when i tap the button.
here's the code:

```
-(void)createTurtle
{

    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(284) + 1;

    NSUInteger randomTitle = arc4random_uniform(1000000) + 1;

    turtle = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    turtle.frame = CGRectMake(r, 0, 36, 47);
    [turtle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"turtle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [turtle addTarget:self action:@selector(turtleTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [turtle setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)randomTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [turtle setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:turtle];
    [self.view addSubview:turtle];



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:16];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, 36, 47);
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}







    - (void) turtleTouched: (id) sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender; // Typecast sender
    button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method won't fire even though you click on it. but it `will fire when you click in its final frame` while animating.

Lets say you button has inital frame of `(0,0,100,100)`,
Now you moving it to a frame of `(200,200,100,100`).

while moving , if you click in region of `(200,200,100,100)-final frame`, then you will get events. but in areas in `middle of path` like `(50,50,100,100)`, you won't get events.

Because when you start animating , the frame of button instantly changes to final frame while the button just transition from initial position to final position.

So, instead of doing it, you can override `touchesBegan` method of your viewController and check whether the touch-point might lie in the `transitional frame`.

```
transitionFrame = [button.layer.presentationLayer frame];
```

**Frame of your button will always be final frame throughout the animation.**

**Code added:**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint p =[((UITouch *)[touches anyObject]) locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect r= [turtle.layer.presentationLayer frame];
    BOOL contains= CGRectContainsPoint(r, p);
    if(contains)
        turtle.hidden=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code  :

```
- (void) turtleTouched: (id) sender 
{
  UIButton *button = sender; // Typecast sender
  button.hidden = YES;
}
```

If you want to hide it on any touch event, use the following :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       buttonNamr.hidden =YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it still does not work. Is there another code like : - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
?

Comment: Can you tell me your exact requirement /

Comment: Yes. The button is moving down with UIViewAnimation. And if i tap the button nothing happens. Does the frame of the button is at the bottom while the button just transition to the final position?

Comment: check my improved answer

Comment: @SamkitJain that wont work.event thought the touches are not on button, you code will hide it. what he wants is hide the button when touch is on it.